# Brand new to Latex

Tags: bibliographies, apa6, annotations

I almost have it figured out. I am just not sure about one final thing. My annotation after the citation is indented way to far to the right. I would like to be able to move the indent of just the annotation.

Here is my main.tex file

```
\documentclass[man,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper, margin=1in}

\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\usepackage{mathptmx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx
\bibliographystyle{apacannx}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\pagestyle{fancy}

\title{Your APA6-Style Manuscript}
\shorttitle{Your APA6-Style Manuscript}
\author{Me} 
\affiliation{University}
%\abstract{Your abstract here} 

\begin{document} 
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\refname}{Annotated bibliography}
\nocite{carlson1984s} 
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
}
```

Here is my sample.bib file

```
@article{carlson1984s,
title={},
author={},
journal={},
volume={},
number={},
pages={},
year={},
publisher={},
doi={},
annote={},
annotate={}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the World of LaTeX. As a very new user, you don't know what is going on yet. That is why your question is pretty unclear to me. Have a look at [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) and [Using LaTeX to write a PhD Thesis](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/index.html). Those are excellent starting points and you will be able to redo your question in a few days :-)

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing this person was trying to do http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13348/fullcite-not-printing-references-in-apa-format. I will read the novice guide and see if I can figure it out from there as well. Thank you

Comment: You can also have a look at [this experimental part of the wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_a_Bibliography).

Comment: @user124577 - `apalike` is based on APA standards of the early 1980s. To implement APA6 standards, one should load the `apacite` citation management package and the `apacite` bibliography style.

Comment: @Mico Sorry, I mixed that up. You're right.

Comment: Welcome to the Dark Side ;-) We've fonts and cookies ;-)

Comment: If the title is on page 2, what's on page 1?

Comment: The first page is the traditional title page. On page two is just the title of the paper at the top of the page.

Comment: Since you're using the `apa6` document class, it shouldn't be necessary to load the `apacite` and `geometry` packages manually. Just add the options `margin=1in` and `natbibapa` to the list of options stated in the `\documentclass` directive.

Comment: The code misses the very very last closing brace. Apart from that it is very good considerung you just started. Keep up and don't feel intimidated by the locals :-)

Comment: You are allowed to askmultiple questions here. Please ask a fresh one.

Comment: Should I repost as a new question?

Comment: @ScottCampbell - Yes -- preferably, with a real bib entry.

Answer (score 1):

You asked,

> How to I get it to say annotated bibliography instead o[f] references?

Issue the instruction

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{Annotated bibliography}
```

somewhere before the `\bibliography{example}` directive. Placing the instruction in the preamble is best.

You also asked,

> How do I basically get rid of the second page?

Based on @Johannes_B's very helpful explanatory comment :-), I assume that what you want is not so much get rid of the entire second page but the repeated title on the second page. This may be achieved by providing the document class option `donotrepeattitle`.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,man, 
       margin=1in,natbibapa,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}

\bibliographystyle{apacannx}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Annotated bibliography}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\pagestyle{fancy}

\title{Your APA6-Style Manuscript}
\shorttitle{Your APA6-Style Manuscript}
\author{Me} 
\affiliation{University}
%\abstract{Your abstract here} 

\begin{document} 
\maketitle

\nocite{carlson1984s} 
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Considering how much the quesion improved, i can overlook that the example is not fully compilable. Helpers here definitely have the knowledge to make it so. `donotrepeattitle` is what he needs.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Thanks for this! I will update my answer with this piece of information.

Comment: Sorry for all the noob questions but I have been using Latex for less than 24 hours. When I use the margin=1in in \documentclass i get the following warning. LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [margin=1in].

Comment: @ScottCampbell - The message about the unused global option would appear to be a bug in the way the document class keeps track of the global options; for sure, the `geometry` package is laoded. and package code does know what to do with this option.

Comment: I was using overleaf.com and I think it is a problem with their system why the page is not working. I switched to sharelatex.com and things are working much much better

Comment: @ScottCampbell - Glad you've found a TeX distribution that's working for you.

Comment: I decided to *not* upvote answers of high-rep users (there are plenty to vote for answers), unless i ask them to write an answer. Your answer has no upvotes  for twelve hours, which is unfair. +1 from my side.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Please see the query http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/297330/5001. If you wouldn't mind providing an upvote to the linked answer, we can start the proceedings to close this holdover query.